# how to set header such as UserAgent with scala?

Tags: scala, user-agent

I am sending request with `scala`：

```
val source = Source.fromURL(new URL("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=00&b=01&c=2009"), "UTF-8")
```

but it seems to be shielded by the yahoo, but I send with browser, everything is normal, so I need to set the property `UserAgent` in my code, how can I set this?

Comment: Doesn't look like you can do it with Source. Use one of the many other http client libraries, maybe dispatch? (http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html)